# How to move or animate a blend object in blender

Tags: animation, blender

I am a beginner in blender and i want to do animation of objects like car ,drones etc 
I have opened a .blend file( which i have downloaded free from a website)   which is a car and i want to animate(moving car ) it using blender.
I used selecting the whole object and then selecting iloc and changing the location but sometimes only the wheel of a car and not the whole body.[blend image opened in blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuVRh.jpg)

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I would first point you to the [blender fundamentals](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6) videos, the first seven will explain the basics. For quick results you could then jump to [29 - parenting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GS452KMVWKA&list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6) and [38 - keyframes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZJswvw9wEs&list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6).

The car you have is made of multiple objects, each needs to be moved together, while you can move them together and animate each object separately, parenting is a way to make multiple objects follow one parent object so that you only need to move and animate the one object.

Another approach which is better suited to complex objects and characters, is to use an [armature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZ3o5tjO51s&list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6), this helps keep related pieces together, yet also allows them to move independently.

One thing to get used to when starting to animate, is that changing frames will cause things to move into their animated positions. This means you need to move to the desired frame before moving things and adding keyframes. While it can be hard to know when you want something in a certain position, you can add keyframes to a new frame, and then move them to a different frame to change the timing, the [dopesheet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHdh8p37yM8&list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6) is normally used to move keyframes to get the timing right.

Also, for blender specific questions there is [blender.stackexchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com)